invalid version requirements for a gradle ignore condition dependabot.yml
I am encountering an issue with my Dependabot.yml file. When adding the following conditions under the ignore section:
package is gradle.
I can't find a way to write the ignore part on the official site.
does anyone have the same issue or know how to fix this?
ignore:
  - dependency-name: "*"
    versions:
      - "*-alpha*"
      - "*-beta*"
      - "*-rc*"
      - "*-SNAPSHOT*"

I received the error: invalid version requirements for a gradle ignore condition.
change the code couple times.
ignore:

dependency-name: '*'
versions: \['*.*-alpha*','*.*-beta\*','*.*-rc\*','*.*-SNAPSHOT\*'\]

